# Minimum android device specs to use google ml kit

Tags: android, google-vision, google-mlkit, google-natural-language

I'm looking for `minimum device specs` required for an android device to run [google ml-kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) without any problems. I could not find it on their official website.

Some of them I required to know were :

- Architecture
- OS
- RAM
- Min Camera resolution

If I missed anything it's important feel free to add. Thanks.

Comment: MLKit is based on Tensorflow Lite which runs on [Raspberry Pi devices](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm#cross-compilation_for_arm_with_bazel) so your "need of know list" reduce down to "it depends".  Realistically it depends on what you are trying to do, i.e. an older device will run slower but whatever feature you are trying to implement could still be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, most ML Kit features support all android os with API level >= 16. Exceptions will be documented in each feature's page. For the camera resolution, it highly depends on each feature and the specific use case, there is no hard requirement so far that applies to all features.